# Convert docx. to pdf in python in linux

Tags: python-3.x, linux, libreoffice

It doesn't create a pdf file in the directory also it prints - None

```
import sys
import subprocess
import re


def convert_to(folder, source, timeout=None):
    args = [libreoffice_exec(), '--headless', '--convert-to', 'pdf', '--outdir', folder, source]

    process = subprocess.run(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                             stderr=subprocess.PIPE, timeout=timeout)
    filename = re.search('-> (.*?) using filter', process.stdout.decode())

    return filename


def libreoffice_exec():
    # TODO: Provide support for more platforms
    if sys.platform == 'darwin':
        return '/Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/MacOS/soffice'
    return 'libreoffice'

result = convert_to('/directory_to_save_file',  '/File_path', timeout=15)
print(result)
```

Could anyone give me solution where I can easily convert docx to pdf? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try below code in your function

```
import subprocess
output = subprocess.check_output(['libreoffice', '--convert-to', 'pdf' ,'demo.docx'])
print output
```

Answer (score 0):

[Aspose.Words for Python](https://pypi.org/project/aspose-words/) provides an ability to convert DOCX and other document formats to PDF. But note, Aspose.Words is a commercial product.
Code is simple - load a document and save it as PDF:

```py
import aspose.words as aw

doc = aw.Document("in.docx")
doc.save("out.pdf")
```

Additional conversions options can be specified using `PdfSaveOptions`, for example PDF compliance:
https://docs.aspose.com/words/python-net/convert-a-document-to-pdf/

```py
import aspose.words as aw

doc = aw.Document("C:\\Temp\\in.docx")
opt = aw.saving.PdfSaveOptions()
opt.compliance = aw.saving.PdfCompliance.PDF_UA1 
doc.save("C:\\Temp\\out.pdf", opt)
```

In addition, when you convert document to PDF, to get an accurate result, the fonts used in the original document should be available in the environment where conversion is performed. Otherwise the fonts are substituted with available ones, that might lead to layout differences due to different font metrics.
https://docs.aspose.com/words/python-net/manipulating-and-substitution-truetype-fonts/